# How to save the output values with each run in the same file in matlab

Tags: matlab, save

I get two different (numeric and character )output values at each run, I want to save these value in a file in order to use them in another process. I saved them  in a struct of array then I saved them in (mat file) as follow:

Sim(i).No
Sim(i).Nam

save('Sim', 'Sim")

I want to saved these value at each run in the same file ... the problem is in the next run I get just the values of the last run.

Comment: consider posting the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Consider loading the struct array from the previous run, then update it (the i'th element?) and save it again.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question at the moment.

Comment: I would like to inform you that I look for the  I didn;tsimilar question but

Comment: sorry for this mistake... I want to say that I looked for if their is similar question but I can't find....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'-append'` option of [SAVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) to add data to a saved file. However, you need to be careful to save each run with a different name, otherwise you'll just be overwriting the save file.

Thus, you could do something like this:

```
for i=1:nRuns

%# create Sim

%# make variable name containing 'i'
simName = ['Sim_',num2str(i)];
saveStruct.(simName) = Sim;
%# save field 'Sim_#', where # is the value of i, to a file 'Sim'
%# in the first iteration, we cannot use append, since the file doesn't exist yet.
if i==1
save('Sim','-struct','saveStruct',simName)
else
save('Sim','-struct','saveStruct',simName,'-append')
end

%# to save memory, re-initialize saveStruct
saveStruct = struct;

end %# loop
```

Comment: Hi... I have tried this code but also give me the last value...please another solution ??

Comment: @zenab: Did you really try? When I tried, it threw an error, which I've now fixed. The file `Sim` will contain a variable `Sim_1` for the first run, `Sim_2` for the second run, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save-to-disk a struct **array** incrementally, so you need to load, appended, and re-save the array each time (something that is not recommended for very large data):

```
% load existing Sim.mat
if exist('Sim.mat','file')
   load('Sim')
end
% check Sim was indeed loaded and if so extend it
if exist('Sim','var') && ~isempty(Sim)
   Sim(end+1).No = No;
   Sim(end+1).Nam = Nam;
else 
   % create a new Sim (presumably the first time)
   Sim(1).No = No;
   Sim(1).Nam = Nam;
end
% save the exented Sim
save Sim Sim
```

The above assumes you have *No* and *Nam* defined earlier in the code. 
If you were running this in a loop, a better approach would be to just keep Sim in memory and save the entire struct array at the end of the loop.